# Как получить значение long для сравнения

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql

Нужно получить значение из партиции для сравнения с основными данными, чтобы вычислить каких партиций не хватает под эти данные. Но `high_value` хранится как `long` и преобразовать его к нормальному типу не получается. Как быть?

```
select to_number(high_value) 
from all_tab_partitions
where table_name = 'XXX' and table_owner = 'YYY'
```

Comment: Не забывайте, что `high_value` может содержать `MAXVALUE`, которое  просто преобразовать в число не получится. Если бы вы объяснили для чего это вам, то возможно вы бы получили более подходящий для вас ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Типы данных LONG и LONG RAW это предшественники CLOB и BLOB соответственно. Они устарели и не рекомендуются к применению. Oracle не предоставляет функций явного преобразования данных этих типов, таких как: `to_char (), to_number ()`. Существует ряд решений, основаных на том, что колонки LONG результата запроса неявно преобразуются в символьный тип данных.

Одно из многих таких решений предлагает [@ChrisSaxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon) на [спроси Тома](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9522731800346411985).
А именно конвертировать как XML:

```
create table parttab1 (id number)
partition by range (id)
interval (1000) (partition p1 values less than (1001));
/

Table PARTTAB1 created.

with xml as (
select dbms_xmlgen.getXmlType (q'[
    select table_name, partition_name, high_value 
    from user_tab_partitions 
    where table_name = upper('parttab1')
    ]') as doc
    from dual
)
select xt.* 
from xml x 
cross join xmlTable('/ROWSET/ROW' passing x.doc columns
    "tableName"     varchar2 (32) path '/ROW/TABLE_NAME',
    "partitionName" varchar2 (32) path '/ROW/PARTITION_NAME',
    "highValue"     varchar2 (96) path '/ROW/HIGH_VALUE'
) xt;
```

Вывод:

```
tableName            partitionName        highValue                              
-------------------- -------------------- ----------------------------------------
PARTTAB1             P1                   1001
```

Для решения задачи как в вопросе, более подойдёт хранимая процедура, например:

```
create or replace function getHighValue (tableName varchar2, partitionName varchar2) return varchar2 is
    ret varchar2 (4000);
begin
    select high_value into ret
    from user_tab_partitions 
    where table_name = upper(tableName)
    and   partition_name = upper (partitionName)
    ;
    return ret;
end getHighValue;
/

select high_value, high_value_length   
from user_tab_partitions
where table_name = upper ('parttab1')
and getHighValue (tableName=>table_name, partitionName=>partition_name) = 1001 
;
```

Вывод:

```
HIGH_VALUE                HIGH_VALUE_LENGTH
------------------------- -----------------
1001                                      4
```

Comment: Ясно, то есть преобразовать не получится? При выводе значения в процедуре через dbms_output оно неявно преобразуется к varchar. Странно, что напрямую такой возможности нет. Но за ответ спасибо.

Comment: А куда вы хотите long преобразовать? Как в вопросе "преобразовать его к нормальному типу" -  не получится потому, что такого типа не существует.

Comment: Мне нужно сравнить его с числовым или текстовым значением в запросе. Или наоборот, преобразовать числовое или текстовое значение в long. То есть сравнить их внутри запроса. Я эти типы и обозвал "нормальными" ))

Comment: Я примерно так и понял, но  в вопросе мало информации, поэтому пока общее решение.

Comment: @АнатолийЭрнст Я переработал ответ. Посмотрите, может теперь он полностью отвечает на ваш  вопроос.

Comment: да, спасибо, так гораздо проще  ))